# Play sound when browser was idle

Tags: javascript, audio

I made system for ordering fast food. System work perfect and have "admin" panel where workpeople received order.
When somebody make order, workpeople on admin panel get sound of order and must receive or reject order.
Orders are checked via ajax every 5 sec.

When browser in full screen and only this site open all work perfect, but when browser was minimized somethimes sound doesn't play. Then if we open browser again, sound play.

I think that browser go idle. I use some extensions for chrome but problem has not gone.

Does anyone have an idea how can I solve this problem.

Thank's...

Comment: That will be the browser itself pausing it. Nothing to do with (any of?) the question's tags.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Probably means `system`.

Comment: Yes - system, write error.